# Extend the list with fixed values

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
l = [5, 6, 7, 1]
```

I need to populate this list with the first value (i.e. 5) so that the length of this list becomes equal to 10.

Expected result:

```
l_extended = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 1]
```

I can do it in for loop:

```
fixed_val = l[0]
len_diff = 10 - len(l)
l_extended = []

for n in range(len_diff):
   l_extended.append(fixed_val)

for n in range(len_diff,10):
   l_extended.append(l[n-len_diff])
```

But is there any shorter way to do it?

Comment: Yep - `lst_extended = [lst[0]] * (to_len - len(lst)) + lst` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also consider

```py
a = [1,2,3]
a_extended = [ a[0] ] * ( 10-len(a) ) + a
```

Explanation:

`a[0]` grabs the first element

`(10-len(a))` is the number of characters we need to add to get the length to 10

In Python, you can do `[1] * 3` to get `[1,1,1]`, so:

`[a[0]] * (10-len(a))` repeats the first element by how many extra elements we need

In python, you can do `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]` to get `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, so:

`[a[0]]*(10-len(a)) + a` adds the extra elements onto the front of the list

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way is probably

```
l_extended = [*[l[0]]*(10 - len(l)), *l]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain it?

Comment: @Fluxy you can print `[l[0]]*(10 - len(l))` to inspect it. The `*iterable` syntax unpacks the elements from an iterable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```py
lst_extended = [lst[0]] * (to_len - len(lst)) + lst
```

`[lst[0]] * some_number`: an array containing `some_number` of the first element of your starting list.

`to_len - len(lst)`: how long the first part of the new list needs to be. So if you want a list of 6 elements from a list of 4 elements, you need 2 extra elements.

`some_list + lst`: join two lists together.

I prefer `lst` to `l` because it looks less like `1` and `I`.